# Rails wicked wizard with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, multi-step, wicked-gem

I want to create a wizard in js.

```
steps   :first_step,
        :second_step
```

In my 'controller_step'

```
def show
        case step
            when :first_step
                @r  = R.new
            when :second_step

            end
        render_wizard
end

def update
        case step
            when :first_step
                @r = R.new(r_params)
            when :second_step

            end

        render_wizard @r
end
```

I have problems after the update of the first step. I'm receive the following error message:

> "Missing template controller_step/second_step, application/second_step
>   with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. ".

How can I force loading of js templete? I would load "second_step.js.erb".

I tried to change the update method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => ( render_wizard @r ) }  
end
```

Of course I get the following error:

> "AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in ...Controller#update Render
>   and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note
>   that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per
>   action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution
>   of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you
>   need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"."

I also tried to change the code (in update):

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :js => ( render_wizard @room_types and return ) } 
end
```

I'm get the same error ( ... application/second_step with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html] .... )

P.S.

In view of the first step:

```
<%= form_for(@r, url: wizard_path, method: :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
   ....
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I fix ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#render_wizard` method defined in the `Wicked::Controller::Concerns::RenderRedirect` is a wrapper method around the `ActionController::Base#render` method. It
accepts a hash of options and passes it down to the controller's regular `#render` method.

This is the source code from the Wicked library:

```
def render_wizard(resource = nil, options = {})
  ...

  if @skip_to
    ...
  else
    render_step wizard_value(step), options
  end
end

def render_step(the_step, options = {})
  if the_step.nil? || the_step.to_s == Wicked::FINISH_STEP
    ...
  else
    render the_step, options #<-- Here
  end
end
```

Your code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => ( render_wizard @r ) }  
end
```

is basically doing:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => ( render @r ) }  
end
```

which is in fact calling the render method twice.

As it is searching for a `.html` template rather than a `.js.erb` one, try adding a `formats: 'js'` option to the render_wizard method. It should prepend ['js'] to the `:formats=>[:html]` we see in the `Missing template` error message.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render_wizard(@r, formats: 'js') }
end
```

also, make sure the template's filename follows the rails convention and start with a `_`. (ie: `_second_step.js.erb`)

---

About the double render error, you are correct. You must return from the controller `#show` or `#update` method and prevent further code from calling the `#render` method a second time. You seem to have fixed that problem already.

EDIT#1

It seems like you may be able to call this method directly in your controller.. :

```
def render_step(the_step, options = {})
  # Wicked::FINISH_STEP = "wicked_finish"
  if the_step.nil? || the_step.to_s == Wicked::FINISH_STEP
    redirect_to_finish_wizard options
  else
    render the_step, options
  end
end
```

I believe `the_step` will be the partial's name. I think you should be able to call the `#render_step` method from your controller.

You may be able to do:

```
def show
  respond_to do |f|
    f.js do
      case step
      when :first_step
          @r  = R.new
          render_step(step) and return
      when :second_step
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You have missed a crucial step in render_redirect.rb: 

`def render_wizard(resource = nil, options = {})
    process_resource!(resource)`
....

When passing a parameter to the method render_wizard , performs process_resource ... 

 `def process_resource!(resource)
    if resource
      if resource.save
        @skip_to ||= @next_step`
 ...

In this case ' if @skip_to' in render_wizard is true .... and execute '`redirect_to wizard_path(@skip_to, @wicked_redirect_params || {}), options'` ...

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but it continues to give the same mistake. The step execute when you pass a params to render_wizard is : `render_step wizard_value(step), options` ( in render_redirect.rb ) because @skip_to is true

Comment: There you go. By passing a resource you were getting redirected to the resource's path! I should have caught that. Let me know once you find a solution! It seems like you would have to bypass the `#render_wizard` method and use the `#render` method so you can specify the partial..

Comment: Ok. If I execute `render :second_step, :formats => 'js'` when I render second step I get this :  `<form .. action="../first_step" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" ...>`. The wizard stay still to the first step ...

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

in r model:

```
validates   :x, presence: true
```

in step controller :

```
...
steps   :first_step,
        :second_step,
        :finish_step
...

def show
    case step
        when :first_step
            @room_types  = R.new
        end

    render_wizard       
end

def update
   case step
      when :view_new_room_type_step
         @r = R.create(r_params)
      when :view_desc_step
         @r = R.find(params[:r][:id])
         @r.update(r_params)
      end

    respond_to do |format|
       if !@r.errors.any?
          format.js { !next_step?(:finish_step) ? ( render next_wizard_path ) : ( redirect_to_finish_wizard ) }
       else
          format.js { render wizard_path, r: @r }
       end
    end
end 

private
        ...

        def redirect_to_finish_wizard
            redirect_to r_index_path , notice: "Ok"
        end
```

in first_step.js.erb

```
$("#modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form_first_step') %>")
```

in _form_first_step.html.erb:

```
<% if @r.errors.any? %>
   <div class="alert fade in alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">&#215;</button>
      <ul>
         <% @r.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <%= content_tag :li, msg, :id => "error_#{msg}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
          <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@room_types, url: wizard_path, method: :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

in second form ( of second step ):

```
<%= form_for(@room_types, url: wizard_path(:second_step), method: :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
    ....
    <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
<% end %>
```

Idea: to validate the data in the steps you can use [jquery-form-validator-rails](https://github.com/gustaflindqvist/jquery-form-validator-rails)